# sbt system level global .sbt file

Tags: scala, sbt

I know I can have my global settings under ~/.sbt .  Is there a system level location where I can put global .sbt files for all users? Essentially, Im planning to put generally useful plugin configurations etc in the file

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about such a feature in sbt. What about symbolic links ?

Comment: Yes, this might work because sbt should pick up all `.sbt` files in `~/.sbt/`.  So, you could have a symbolic link from `~/.sbt/system.sbt` to `/etc/sbt/system.sbt` and users could still have their own settings in `~/.sbt/user.sbt`, for example.

Comment: @mark .. Im doing something like this right now.. I was just wondering if there a less intrusive way . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not found a way to do this either with sbt directly, you could try adding your default settings as symbolic links in /etc/skel/.sbt/plugins and store the actual default settings in (for example) /etc/sbt/settings/global.sbt.

Create a symbolic link to each file in /etc/sbt/settings/ to /etc/skel/.sbt/plugins and any new users will automatically get the global settings and any changes will be automatically propagated as well.

You will have to manually add the links to existing users though (unless there is a means of updating a user's home from the skeleton after their creation?)

Answer (score -1):

a better way to do this is:
1. write an `autoplugin` with `autoImport` and triggers as `allDependencies`(and don't have your plugin to depend on any other plugin)
2. publish your plugin to a repo(of your organization)....or publish is locally if all the users are using a shared machine
3. include the plugin in whatever project it's needed